# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

I am running a script which takes around 45 mins. The script interacts with MySQL multiple times in between but at the end the script got stopped and generated following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified           MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBeginConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress, LazyAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateSocketStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, IPAddress ip, Boolean unix)
at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean unix)
at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
at Connection.ExecuteNonQuery(String str)
at BulkEmailSender.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The script was able to connect multiple times than what could have happened?

Comment: MySQL is on Linux server. Anybody can help?